# Angular 2 dev extreme dx-date-box validation of required field

Tags: validation, angular, devextreme

I'm trying to use dx-date-box for date inputs but I can't make it validate required values on my form:

```
<dx-date-box placeholder="Request Date" required="true"
          formControlName="request_date" type="date" validationMessageMode="always" invalidDateMessage="{{VALIDATION.DATE_INVALID}}">
        </dx-date-box>
```

Invalid date validation is working and it shows the message, but it wont to validate required value and doesn't show required error.
I'm not sure how to achieve that behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code from DevExtreme Documentation

Add `dx-validator="dobValidationRules"` to element and in angularJS, define `dobValidationRules`.

```
$scope.dobValidationRules = {
        validationRules: [{
            type: "required",
            message: "Date of birth is required"
        }, {
            type: "range", 
            max: maxDate, 
            message: "You must be at least 21 years old"
        }]
    };
```

Please find the actual working version [here](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Validation/Overview/AngularJS/Light/)

Comment: Thanks, man. this link saved me a lot of time. I'm using it on angular 2 so I found example there. I would give you 10 upwotes if I could