# How do I indicate a DevExtreme dx-date-box is required?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, devextreme

So far I've found this related answer: [Angular 2 dev extreme dx-date-box validation of required field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503999/angular-2-dev-extreme-dx-date-box-validation-of-required-field)

And this supposedly helpful AngularJS example: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Validation/Overview/AngularJS/Light/

...but none of this is working for me in an Angular 6 project. There doesn't seem to be a `dx-validator` (or `dxValidator`) property that I can set. I've used:

```
@ViewChild(DxDateBoxComponent) dateBox: DxDateBoxComponent;
```

...to get a reference to the date box component, but I haven't found any methods on the object I can use, or fields I can set, to get the job done. Whatever `this.dataBox.validator` is, it requires a bunch of private fields that I wouldn't know how to define, so I don't think it has anything to do with the kind of validators I've seen in the examples I've looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally stumbled on the answer I was looking for. Unlike the examples I found that looked like this:

```
<dx-date-box dx-validator="myValidatorRules"...
```

...which **didn't** translate from AngularJS to Angular like this:

```
<dx-date-box [dx-validator]="myValidatorRules"...
```

...what I needed was to add `dx-validator` not as an attribute, but as a nested component:

```
<dx-date-box...>
  <dx-validator [validationRules]="myValidatorRules"></dx-validator>
</dx-date-box>
```

With that, adding validation rules to `myValidatorRules` works just like in the sample code I've seen, in this case needing the rule `{type: 'required'}`.